# Perforce like client specs mappings with Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, perforce, perforce-client-spec

We recently moved from Perforce to Mercurial and love it!

One little problem: after much research we can't figure out how to map a special directory in the repository to some special place on the client. Here is an example of our hg repo:

```
/foo/source files
/bar/source files
/build
    /macosx/mac make files
    /win/windows make files
```

With Perforce, we were using client spec mappings to map //depot/build/macosx/... to just /build/... on the Mac client, and //depot/build/win/... to /build/... on the Windows dev box. Directories foo and bar are synced as is. Makefiles in /foo and /bar assume that our build makefiles are located in /build and we would like to keep them as is. The final client set of files should look like this:

```
/foo/source files
/bar/source files
/build/client specific make files
```

I've read about subrepos, but this solution does not seem to be client specific.

Any idea how to solve this problem will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can't check out only portions of a repository with Mercurial.

You always get a clone containing everything, and the working directory will also contain everything.

With Mercurial you should strive to have 1 repository for 1 project, so that everything you get logically belongs together, and then you shouldn't have much need for just a portion of it.

This also means that whatever directory structure you have in your Mercurial repository will always match exactly the structure you have on disk.

Comment: Thanks, Lasse! In that case what's the best solution to our problem? All we need is files in /build/macosx appear under /build on the Mac clients, and /build/win in /build on the Windows clients... I guess a copy script could have solved it, but we would have to run that copy command each time something in the build system changes.

Comment: Why can't the files that refer to /build/ refer to the correct directory based on the platform it is on?

Comment: We are talking about hundreds of makefiles, each ending with: include ../Build/build.mak

Comment: I suppose the best way is to replace them with include ../build/build.mak with $(build)/build.mak, when $(build) is set as an environment variable. It's a pity that Mercurial does not provide a flexibility of client specs mappings...

Comment: That's a matter of opinion. I can certainly understand the need to check out a partial copy of the repository, but I would never check out directories in anything but their original relative configuration and then make relative references to them. I would always have a repository that would work out of the box if I just grab everything in their default configuration.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen it's a powerful feature when viewed in the context of things such as build systems and shared libraries. For instance, if you have a shared library and project that

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with Mercurial as it doesn't have the concept of a client separate from a depot.

However, you can use a symlink on Mac OS X (ln -s) and a junction on windows (mklink on Vista and up using the junction tool on XP http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) to solve this problem on the file system level.

Alternatively you can use a variable in the Makefiles to refer to the build directory (eg `$(BUILD)/something.ext` instead of `build/something.ext`).

Comment: Can he map a sub-folder to be the parent? That is, can you map /a/b to be /a? And won't this confuse Mercurial? Sounds like he would need tell Mercurial to ignore the contents of /build/, but that would make comitting changes to the sub-directories hard as well. I'd go with the mapping in software, that is, the scripts should handle this.

Comment: Hmm, an option with variables seems to be the best! And it will work on all platforms. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This sort of mapping cannot be done in Mercurial.  There is an outstanding TODO item for 'narrow' clones so you can check out just a subdirectory.  And I could see an implementation of that supporting that sort of functionality.  But then again, I know that something like this would be considered a little too 'clever' (read complex) and there would be a lot of push-back on the idea.

In the meantime, I would suggest one of these two solutions.

1. Symbolic links.  Put the symbolic link to your `build` directory in your `.hgignore` file. Then each person can make their own symbolic link to the appropriate directory of build files.  This has the disadvantage of not working on a platform without symbolic links.
2. An environment variable that's used in a top level makefile to construct the path to the platform specific makefile it should be calling.

Comment: That would mean that anything changed in /build/macosx and /build/windows would be a bit more difficult to handle, but perhaps the /build/ directory should be renamed to allow for this.